# Javascript date conversion issue

Tags: javascript, datetime

I work on a large work system with many JS pages each using the built in Date()  function.

I've just been informed of a bug where american ipads throw an error on calendars and other pages due to the system needing date formats as DD/MM/YYYY, but the  american timezone on ipads the date returned is MM/DD/YYYY.

Would anyone be able to suggest any other solutions other than going to every location a new Date is instantiated and using getTime() to create my date from that?

Current calendar initialization code:

```
date        = new Date(),
firstDayISO = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1),
lastDayISO  = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0),
firstDay    = ISOFromDate(firstDayISO),
lastDay     = ISOFromDate(lastDayISO);


function ISOFromDate(dteDate) {

    chrDate = dteDate.getFullYear();
    chrDate += "-";
    chrDate += pad(dteDate.getMonth() + 1, 2);
    chrDate += "-";
    chrDate += pad(dteDate.getDate(), 2);

    return chrDate;

}
```

Comment: Well, how are you creating that date string right now...?

Comment: Convert all your dates into UTC formats and forget about timezone issues

Comment: It's way more complicated than you think. Specially when you don't post any code.

Comment: @stackErr That sounds like a terrible idea for a *calendar*

Comment: @stackErr That's not necessarily true, you may want to display the time in the original timezone, so you may need to pass along the timezone

Comment: @Phylogenesis `calendars and other pages` but I agree it might not be the best solution. The OP asked a vague/general question and I answered with the most general solution

Comment: @JuanMendes Agreed, read my comment to Phylogenesis above

Comment: @deceze Apologies uploaded to include my calendar initialization code for you

Comment: @stackErr I've updated the original post to contain code snippet on how dates are initialized, Thanks

Comment: So the important parts are in `ISOFromDate`, which we don't see...?

Comment: @deceze Sorry forgot to post, I've updated it with the function also :), Thanks

Comment: what specific error is being thrown?

Comment: @Julie no error is being thrown, my calendar just thinks it's february right now instead of march because the calendar is setting the dates as MM/DD/YYYY instead of DD/MM/YYYY for some reason

Comment: @does_not_compute which value is incorrect: `firstDay` or `firstDayISO`?

Comment: @does_not_compute this does not seem to be an issue necessarily with your javascript.  What calendar plugin are you using and how are you configuring it?